# Creating a System.Configuration.Configuration by merging two config files?

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config, app-config

I have two .config files, and I need a [System.Configuration.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) that is a partial merge between them?

I can read the files as XML and create the desired merge easily, but then it's a string or XDocument. However, .net's System.Configuration seems to be stricly file based, so I would have to write it to a temp directory which I'd like to avoid.

Is there a way to do that?

Example, `config1.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="CacheTime" value="300" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyBehavior">
               <!-- snipped -->
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and `config2.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
     <client>
          <endpoint name="MyEndpoint" address="net.tcp://...."
            behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding"
            contract="IMyContract">
          </endpoint>
     </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The resulting Configuration should then be the union of these two, so that I have both the AppSetting and the Endpoint. Now, this example contains WCF, but I'm *not* looking for a WCF specific solution, as I absolutely need a System.Configuration.Configuration object.

config1 and config2 are just examples - the actual combination of them is non-deterministic, I might have config1 and config4 or config 3 and config4 or config2 and config3.

Comment: Hi Michael. The config files are disjoint? Can you post a little example of both, and the result you expect? I'd be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to simply make your configuration files more modular (and potentially protect file access to particular sections), have a look at [System.Configuration.SectionInformation.ConfigSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx).

Comment: configSource only accepts a single override sadly. In this case it won't do any good as the actual configuration combinations are non-deterministic. will clarify question.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, I can think of no ways to do this other than messing with XmlDocument and writing a temporary file to load, as you mentioned. Watching this in curiosity though; you never know.